# Sum up Time column using sql query

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table as follows

```
repID   ClockIn     ClockOut    TotalHours
109145  7:50:50 AM  3:37:16 PM  7:46:26
109145  7:52:41 AM  3:44:51 PM  7:52:10
109145  8:42:40 AM  3:46:29 PM  7:3:49
109145  7:50:52 AM  3:42:59 PM  7:52:7
109145  8:09:23 AM  3:36:55 PM  7:27:32
```

Here '`TotalHours`' column is obtained as diff of ClockIn and ClockOut

Now I need to add all the data in column '`TotalHours`' Whose datatype in (`varchar`).

How should I add this column.....

I tried as

```
select SUM(TotalHours)
```

But it returns an error:

> Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator

I also tried with casting it into `float`, `datetime` and `time`...

But all returns error...

Please help to sum up the time column....

Answer (score 4):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6adbe/41)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table2
    ([repID] int, [ClockIn] datetime, [ClockOut] datetime, [TotalHours] varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    ([repID], [ClockIn], [ClockOut], [TotalHours])
VALUES
    (109145, '7:50:50 AM', '3:37:16 PM', '7:46:26'),
    (109145, '7:52:41 AM', '3:44:51 PM', '7:52:10'),
    (109145, '8:42:40 AM', '3:46:29 PM', '7:3:49'),
    (109145, '7:50:52 AM', '3:42:59 PM', '7:52:7'),
    (109145, '8:09:23 AM', '3:36:55 PM', '7:27:32')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(8), dateadd(second, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, ClockIn, ClockOut)), 0),  108)
from Table2
group by repID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6adbe/10/0)**:

```
| COLUMN_0 |
------------
| 14:02:04 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select sum(datediff(second,ClockIn,ClockOut))/3600 as hours_worked
from Table2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6adbe/10/1)**:

```
| hours_worked|
------------
|       38 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select sum(datediff(minute, 0, TotalHours)) / 60.0 as hours_worked
from Table2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6adbe/10/2)**:

```
| HOURS_WORKED |
----------------
|           38 |
```

Here the last query has been taken from FreeLancers answer as i was eager to know whether it works or not.

Here, First you need to convert your datetime difference into either second or minute and then convert that time back to the hour.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Renuka : in that case you should consider the first query. As hours are 38 it is the next day so that it is showing 14:02:04

Comment: I want it as 38... but also want the remaining mins and sec to be displayed.. Eg:38:02:04

Comment: @Renuka : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6adbe/40 Not the best solution but solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since TotalHours is varchar , we need to convert it to time first . Try the following code

```
select sum(datediff(minute,'0:00:00',CONVERT(time,TotalHours)))/60.0 as TotalHoursWorked
```

One way to get the output in HH:MM is -

```
select left(right(convert(varchar(20),cast(sum(datediff(minute,'0:00:00',CONVERT(datetime,TotalHours)))/86400.0 as datetime)),8),6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Following:

```
select sum(datediff(minute, 0, TotalHours)) / 60.0 as hours_worked
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But this too returns error as 'Operand data type datetime is invalid for sum operator'

Comment: The Query returns as
7.050000
7.450000
7.766666
15.733333 But I want result as the sum of all the time from the column 'TotalHours'

Comment: It works... I made wrong in group statement... Thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select sum(datediff(s,ClockIn,ClockOut))
```

- to get the result in seconds.

Comment: Hi... It returns the datediff of each row... But I want the sum of all data in 'TotalHours' column

Comment: @Renuka: They should be the same thing, since TotalHours is the time difference between ClockIn and ClockOut.

Comment: Thanks... It works... I made wrong in group statement... Thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is to old but i found best option for this.
Try this:

```
select  cast(sum(datediff(second,0,dt))/3600 as varchar(12)) + ':' + 
        right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,dt))/60%60 as varchar(2)),2) +
        ':' + right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,dt))%60 as varchar(2)),2)
from    TestTable
```