# how can I calculate time in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called **total_hours** which is a set of times in Time type and it is in **HH:MM:SS** format in **SQL server**. I want to know how can I get the **sum of total_hours**.

For example:
total_hours

```
00:10:30
01:20:00
00:20:00
---------
01:50:30
```

Could you please give me the query to exactly do the same thing with the same format?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: homeworkSolver.solveProblem(3.2.25);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834549/sum-up-time-column-using-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT SUM( DATEPART(SECOND, [time]) + 60 * 
              DATEPART(MINUTE, [time]) + 3600 * 
              DATEPART(HOUR, [time] ) 
            ) as 'TotalTime' 
FROM Table1
```

(Or)

```
SELECT dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0, [Time])),0) 
FROM Table1
```